# Going crazy with php5apache2_4.dll not found

Tags: php, apache-http-server, wamp, php5

I have a computer with Win XP SP3 and I was going to install a WAMP system on it.
I already had a pwerfectly working WAMP ([Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com/), it is a portable wamp that works on usb stick) on another computer (Win7) so I simply copied the whole folder to the same position (c:\uniserver) but starting the server on winxp failed with the error "php5apache2_4.dll not found".

So I went to download the single packages (apache 2.4, php 5.4.11), using this [website](http://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-and-mysql-5-5-21-on-windows-7/) as reference.

Extracted Apache 2.4 on c:\apache24, started and worked like a charm ("it works" page loaded fine)

Downloaded php 5.4.11 thread safe (VC9, since VC6 does not exist for 5.4) and I got the same "php5apache2_4.dll not found" error.

Deleted php 5.4.11, cleaned everything, installed php 5.4.9, downloaded the php5apache2_4.dll for php 5.4.9 from apachelounge, got the same error :(

How the hell I'm supposed to have a wamp working with latest version of everything? The  php5apache2_4.dll file is there, and the path is right, but still apache gives me the error and does not start (but if I delete everything about php it start to work again), and even the uniform server wamp does not work. What I'm supposed to do now?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't ever copy an install onto another OS/Computer. I suggest you do a clean installation and just copy your www folder from the previous system.

Comment: Uniform server is a portable wamp, it is supposed to work in a usbstick. And as I have explained, I have also done a clean installation with the separate packages.